# I'm using react-native reanimated latest version but it's not working on android platform

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
/Users/macbook/LatestBackup/naviDemo/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/src/reactNativeVersionPatch/ReanimatedUIManager/70/com/swmansion/reanimated/layoutReanimation/ReanimatedUIManager.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
class ReaUiImplementationProvider extends UIImplementationProvider {
^
symbol: class UIImplementationProvider

I'm facing this issue in android platform

I have tried this  implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.70.2'. instead of  implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+" solution too but not working. Apart from this i have also tried this

configurations.all {

```
        resolutionStrategy {

          force 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.70.2'

        }
   }
```

after adding the resolutionStrategy code.My app just got crash. I'm facing this issue in react-native-reanimated npm in android.

I've already check content in my bash profile and everything is fine but still facing the issue.

Please help me

Comment: Please help me i got stuck here

Comment: I checked react-native-reanimated in other project and its working fine and after a day i used yarn start --reset-cache command and its working fine in mine project too